# How to parse xml with simplexml?

Tags: php, simplexml

I am trying to parse the following xml but my code blew parses the first tag of each section only,

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);       
foreach ($xml->person as $p) {
  $p = $p->attributes()->name;
  echo "     ".$p. "        ";
}
```

The output is Joe Ray Alex, but I need it to show the name of every person in the list, so it should be Joe Jack Ray John Edward Alex.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <people>
   <person name="Joe">
   <person name="Jack">
   </person>
   </person>

   <person name="Ray">
   <person name="John">
   <person name="Edward">
   </person>
   </person>

   <person name="Alex">
   </person>
 </people>
```

Is there any other option rather than changing the xml?
because I receive the xml as a response from a web service.

Comment: Your xml is invalid. Also are you sure this is the structure you should be using? The nesting (without any context) seems unusual.

Comment: You are missing at least one end tag.

Answer (score 1):

1. Fix Your XML
2. IF you really want to print inner element data, you should make a recursive function:

   ```
   function printNames($simpleXMLElement) {

       // Print the name attribute of each top level element
       foreach ($simpleXMLElement as $element) {

           // Print this elements name.
           $p = $simpleXMLElement->attributes()->name;
           echo "     ".$p."        ";

           // Send the inner elements to get their names printed
           foreach ($simpleXMLElement->children() as $child) {
               printNames($child);
           }
       }
   }


   $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
   printNames($xml);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it does not show anything, the output is empty

Answer (score 0):

Why not correct the XML?

i.e.

```
<people>
   <person name="Joe" />
   <person name="Jack" />

   <person name="Ray" />
   <person name="John" />
   <person name="Edward" />

   <person name="Alex" />
 </people>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your odd XML structure, you either have to look for and recurse down into any `person` elements you find, or you need to generate a flat list of all `person` elements.

Here is an xpath approach:

```
$people = $xml->xpath('descendant::person');

foreach ($people as $person) {
    echo $person['name'], "\n";
}
```